# how do i make a displacement map on this model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, image, displacement

I am trying to make a displacement map using this photo on this model, however I have no idea how to do this, could someone please point me in the right direction?
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please tell a bit more, are you sure that you want to give a displacement map to the surface of this object? Because it would mean subdivide it a lot, which will make it heavier for animations and render, is it what you want?